# What is the word that means "directory" or "file"?

Tags: file, directory, terminology, file-handling

I'm trying to name an object that can be a file or a directory.  What's the correct terminology for this?

I've considered

handle -> rejected, object is not a handle

address -> rejected, object is not an address

object -> rejected, too generic, should be better terminology

When I say "object" in my first sentence, I'm specifically talking about a `<div>` in an HTML DOM, but it could be anything.

To put my question a different way, what's the parent word of the children "file" and "directory"?  e.g. a `foo` can be a file, or a directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've heard the phrase "file system object", although it's painful to say :)

Comment: Ahh I'm glad someone understood my question.  Agreed, difficult to say, but it's a start!  :)  Maybe "FSO"

Comment: It's funny because a directory is a file and a file is a file.... its all files 0_0

Comment: @Jesus - that's almost an answer in itself, just call everything a file. :/

Comment: Yeah but the word association will make it OH SO CONFUSING to anyone working on that code, inode works pretty well and so does FSO, I would prefer FSO though because it's a tad more descriptive and inode usually refers to hard drive data/metadata (at least for me).

Answer (score 3):

In Unix we call any file and directory an `inode`, since a file is not many different from a directory in binary representation.

Answer (score 3):

So just for reference Java has a File class that can be a directory or a standard file. Basically treating a directory as a special case of a file. [java.io.File class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html)

Also, you could go old school and just name it AbstractFile.

Comment: AbstractFile is an interesting option too...rolls 'em up into one.

Answer (score 1):

In Unix, everything -- both a directory and a file -- is a **file**.